# How do you go from VESA 100x100 to VESA 200x200?

Tags: display, vesa

None of the adapter brackets or plates I've tried handle the VESA 200x200 end correctly.  The holes aren't large enough for the standard VESA 200x200 M8 screws, which seems really odd.

Background: I'm trying to mount a lightweight VESA 200x200 panel onto a monitor arm that has 75x75 and 100x100 holes.

Comment: Could you use your (or a friend's) electric drill to drill-out the holes to the size needed for your M8 bolts?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and this is what I eventually did.  But it was VERY dangerous if you don't have the right tools.  Even with a vice, a good drill, and a special metal drill bit, it was hard to drill the holes larger.  The metal came lose many times, almost cutting my hand, etc.  I think you'd need an actual drill press to do this properly, not just a drill and vice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mount**: VESA mounting standard [MIS-F](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_Display_Mounting_Interface) allows for 200 x 200 mm spacing of holes and specifies *either M6 or M8 bolts*.

**Bolts**: M6 bolts have a 6mm diameter shank, M8 bolts 8mm.

**Holes**: Recommended hole sizes are 6.4-6.55 and 8.4-8.55mm respectively. [(ref)](http://www.brook-tech.fsnet.co.uk/Clearance%20Holes%20+%20Tolerance.pdf)

**Washers**: M6 or M8 washers have an internal diameter of 7.0-6.6mm and 9.4-9.0mm respectively. [(ref)](http://www.roymech.co.uk/Useful_Tables/Screws/Hex_Screws.htm)

**Hypothesis**: Perhaps your "VESA 200 x 200" adapter plate is for M6 bolts and has hole diameter approx 6.5mm?

Comment: WOW! THANK YOU.  That would explain a lot.  Now I'll need to go see if they make M6 to M8 sleeves of some sort.  My panel has M8 sockets, but virtually all of the adapters seem to have M6 holes, so I basically need a filler.

Answer (score 0):

You need a VESA conversion plate. Sometimes these are also called adapter plates.

Here is one at Amazon [http://www.amazon.com/Arrowmounts-AM-201C-Conversion-Mounts-extend/dp/B0029Y1CRA/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1322354643&sr=8-3](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0029Y1CRA)

It should work provided that your arm has enough strength to hold the panel.

Comment: Thank you, BUT strangely no, this will not work.  I realize my comment sounds like nonsense - that's why I've been posting.  I've tried several of these, maybe even that exact one, and the holes are too small.  See the next answer, he's saying some additional standard allows for M6 screws, which are a bit smaller.